# Including CSS with a javascript widget without messing up host page

Tags: javascript, css, twitter-bootstrap, widget

I'm making a widget type thing that relies on some CSS from bootstrap. This widget will be inserted into the host page something like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://mydomain.com/MyWidget.ashx?param1=value"></script>
<div id="com-mydomain-widget-placeholder"></div>
```

Where *MyWidget.ashx* will do a bunch of work and load up `#com-mydomain-widget-placeholder` with some html for my widget.

My question is, what do I do with my CSS?  I'm using lots of the twitter boostrap library to do things, but it seems very time consuming to extract everything I'm using and create different names/classes for it.  But also, if I include the whole bootstrap css file it might screw up my clients webpage (it won't in my case..but I'd like to do this the right way).  How do I go about doing this?

Also is there a way to detect if they perhaps have already loaded the twitter Bootstrap CSS things?

Answer (score 0):

If the host page used an IFrame to load the widget, that should isolate the DOMs from each other.

Comment: Something I've thought about, using an IFrame rather than a just inlining the content, was just worried about the other problems iFrames would bring up..(sizing issues and cross scripting stuff)...if this is the only way to do what i'm looking for though, then I guess it's what I'll have to go with